# Too Many Requests - Geoplugin

Tags: php

why after I upload my website I keep getting the following error when I try to call a function that uses Geoplugin? even though it works fine on the local server.

I googled and found possible answers: **allow_url_fopen** must be turned on in php configuration. I contacted my hosting support but they said nothing is wrong from their end.

Please, what should I do to solve this problem??

HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests

Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=154.160.16.108): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests in /home/xxxxx/joacmedia.com/xxxx/xxx/myfunc.php on line 578

MY PHP FUNCTION :

```
//get some deatils about users using geoplugin
function jo_ip_info($ip = NULL, $purpose = "location") {
  $output = NULL; global $countries;

  if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE) {
      $ip = jo_real_ip();
  }

  $purpose    = str_replace(array("name", "\n", "\t", " ", "-", "_"), NULL, strtolower(trim($purpose)));
  $support    = array("country", "countrycode", "state", "region", "city", "location", "address");
  $continents = array(
      "AF" => "Africa",
      "AN" => "Antarctica",
      "AS" => "Asia",
      "EU" => "Europe",
      "OC" => "Australia (Oceania)",
      "NA" => "North America",
      "SA" => "South America"
  );
  if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && in_array($purpose, $support)) {
      $ipdat = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip));
      if (@strlen(trim($ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode)) == 2) {
          switch ($purpose) {
              case "location":
                  $output = (object) array(
                      "city"           => @$ipdat->geoplugin_city,
                      "state"          => @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName,
                      "country"        => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName,
                      "country_abbr"   => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode,
                      "continent"      => @$continents[strtoupper($ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode)],
                      "continent_code" => @$ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode,
                      "currency"       => @$ipdat->geoplugin_currencyCode,
                      "request_ip"     => @$ipdat->geoplugin_request,
                      "time_zone"      => @$ipdat->geoplugin_timezone,
                      "country_code"   => @$countries[$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode]['code']
                  );
                  break;
              case "address":
                  $address = array($ipdat->geoplugin_countryName);
                  if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_regionName) >= 1)
                      $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                  if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_city) >= 1)
                      $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                  $output = implode(", ", array_reverse($address));
                  break;
              case "city":
                  $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                  break;
              case "state":
                  $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                  break;
              case "region":
                  $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                  break;
              case "country":
                  $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName;
                  break;
              case "countrycode":
                  $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode;
                  break;
          }
      }
  }
  return $output;

 }


//get real ip of a user
function jo_real_ip($ip='')


{

 $ip = filter_var($ip,FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)  ? $ip : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && preg_match_all('#\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}#s', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], $matches)) {
      foreach ($matches[0] AS $xip) {
          if (!preg_match('#^(10|172\.16|192\.168)\.#', $xip)) {
              $ip = $xip;
              break;
          }
      }
  } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && preg_match('/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
      $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
  } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']) && preg_match('/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])) {
      $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
  } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']) && preg_match('/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'])) {
      $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
  }
  return $ip;

 }
```

Comment: Obviously the geo-API does only allow a certain ammount of request per time..

Comment: I noticed since yesterday...and their documentation says a limit of 120 requests per minute. so I don't see why it's not working on the remote server

Comment: There's a FAQ, maybe you get answers through it (f.e. your hosters IP could have been blacklisted...)

Comment: @LarsStegelitz ....yes am guessing so. and am on a shared hosting plan too...their Geoplugin faq is saying there might be someone on the same server who is using the plugin. To solve this problem i have to upgrade to premium service to extend the number of request or whitelist my domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in Geoplugin FAQ: Geoplugin seems to be blocking HTTP requests and they require that I use premium service. And since am in the process of development it will be useless to purchase their premium service.

I have to rewrite the function to use at least a free and stable `ip-api`:https://ip-api.com/ and everything working.

```
        //DETECT USER'S IP
          function jo_real_ip($ip ='',$detect_deep = TRUE)
          {
            
             $ip = filter_var($ip,FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)  ? $ip : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
              if ($detect_deep) {
                if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && preg_match_all('#\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}#s', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], $matches)) {
                  foreach ($matches[0] AS $xip) {
                      if (!preg_match('#^(10|172\.16|192\.168)\.#', $xip)) {
                          $ip = $xip;
                          break;
                      }
                  }
              } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && preg_match('/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
                  $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
              } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']) && preg_match('/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])) {
                  $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
              } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']) && preg_match('/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'])) {
                  $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
              }
              }

              return $ip;

          }

        //JO_IP_INFO FUNCTION WILL FEED US WITH INFORMATION ABOUT THE USER
        function jo_ip_info($ip = NULL, $purpose = "location"){
          $output = NULL; global $countries;
          if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE) {
                  $ip = jo_real_ip();
              }
          $purpose    = str_replace(array("name", "\n", "\t", " ", "-", "_"), NULL, strtolower(trim($purpose)));
          $support    = array("country", "countrycode", "state", "region", "city", "location", "address");
          if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && in_array($purpose, $support)) {
            $fields= "status,continent,continentCode,country,countryCode,region,regionName,city,district,zip,lat,lon,timezone,currency,isp,org,as,query";
            $ipdat = (object) json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ip-api.com/json/{$ip}?fields={$fields}"),TRUE); 

            if ( isset($ipdat->status) && $ipdat->status ==='success') {
              switch ($purpose) {
                case 'location':
                  $output = (object) array(
                    "city"           => @$ipdat->city,
                    "state"          => @$ipdat->regionName,
                    "country"        => @$ipdat->country,
                    "country_abbr"   => @$ipdat->countryCode,
                    "continent"      => @$ipdat->continent,
                    "continent_code" => @$ipdat->continentCode,
                    "currency"       => @$ipdat->currency,
                    "latitude"       => @$ipdat->lat,
                    "longitude"      => @$ipdat->lon,
                    "request_ip"     => @$ipdat->query,
                    "time_zone"      => @$ipdat->timezone,
                    "country_code"   => @$countries[$ipdat->countryCode]['code'],
                    "zip"            => @$ipdat->zip,
                    "organization"   => (object) array('isp'=> @$ipdat->isp,'org'=>@$ipdat->org,'org_number'=>@$ipdat->as)
                    
                  );
                break;
                case'address':
                  $output = implode(', ', array_reverse(
                    @$ipdat->country,
                    @$ipdat->state,
                    @$ipdat->city,
                    @$ipdat->district));
                break;
                case 'city':
                $output = @$ipdat->city; 
                break;
                case 'country':
                $output = @$ipdat->country;
                break;
                case 'countrycode':
                $output = $countries[$ipdat->countryCode]['code'];
                break;
                case 'state':
                $output = @$ipdat->regionName;
                break;
                case 'district':
                $output  = @$ipdat->district;
                break;
                case 'timezone':
                $output = @$ipdat->timezone;
                break;

              }
            }

            return $output;

          }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you , I implemented this case in such a way that when GeoPlugin works, I receive data from it, and when not , I receive from ip-api that you introduced, this is always the right request and works for me .